# How to animate TextView's weight property

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I have a TextView, and I want to change its size, so I use its layout_weight property. When I set it:
`textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, newWeight));`
It works well. However, I want to animate the change. Can I do this (without using a thread that will change it every so and so millis), using the animation classes?

Answer (score 1):

Property animations are only possible in Honeycomb as of now. A way to handle your requirement would be to use a scale animation. The tricky part is to calculate the scale factor. But it should be possible. You can add the scale animation to your view. And if you add the an animation listener to the animation object you can set the layout params on the animation end event so that the view actually re sizes.

Comment: In the time limit I have, this is too much... I will leave it for the buffer time of the project (== probably will not happen). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the weight of a view using Android animations.
You can use `Handler` to do a `postDelayed` event, where the view weight can be changed until some limit.

```
Handler hdlr = new Handler() {
    onMessage(Message msg) {

    }
};

hndlr.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     void run() {
         // change the weight and post another delayed messge if required.
     }
};
```